# German Nonsense

Tags: synonym

Ludwig Wittgenstein uses two words, 'unsinnig' and 'sinnlos', in his writing to indicate, seemingly, 'ridiculous nonsense' and 'empty and lacking sense', resp. In English, a fair transation would seem to be the difference between 'silly nonsense' and 'technically meaningless'. Now, the literal translation for 'illogical' seems to be 'unlogisch'.

For instance, Noam Chomsky's ['Colorless green ideas sleep furiously'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously) is both 'unlogisch' since green can't be colorless, and the statement on its face isn't ridiculous in the same way 'up Jack red red Berlin dialtheia' is, which is clearly 'Unsinn'.

Given this understanding of 'unsinnig', 'sinnlos', and 'unlogisch', what sort of options does one have translating 'absurdity' into into German when describing language and language use? Is it confined to these three terms, or are there other non-idiomatic terms that might serve a purpose, and if so, what are typical that might come to mind of a native German speaker?

Comment: Are there other non-idiomatic terms? [You tell me](https://www.dict.cc/?s=absurdity)

Comment: @infinitezero Thanks for the list from your preferred site. I'll examine the entries.

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/absurd#ot-1 I don't know if it is possible to link to specific synonym groups under the Thesaurus heading. The first and last group are applicable to language and its usage. The second-to-last seems mostly to collect derogatory terms.

Comment: @ccprog Vielen Dank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what sort of options does one have translating 'absurdity' into into German when describing language and language use?

That's an entirely pragmtic decision to make. If I were to insult a poorly written question, I would usually opt for *Schwachsinn*, which ultimately translates to *whacky* rather than *swag*. And all though *Schwachsinniger* has the same ableist connotation as *retard* might, it will be useful to note that *idiot* in the same sense goes further back and simply acquired the connotation by force of attraction.

A more literal translation of *Schwachsinn*, as it describes most of the German stack etymology discussion, which revolves around folk reinterpretation and an anal retentive insistence on the selective written record, would be "weak minded". This isn't entirely correct, however, as *Schwachsinn* seems to be the norm and not a mental impediment out of the norm.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be a term that emphasizes a pejorative in a way that 'Das ist Unsinn.' doesn't. It also apparently captures the idea of 'intellectually unsophisticated'.

Comment: The common saying holds, *der Ton macht die Musik*. *Unsinn* might be a little more neutral, more often directed at children, but it can be used as a synonym to *Schwachsinn* because it's all in how you say it. So I wouldn't use either of these in writing because it is liable for overinterpretation when the intonation is missing.

Answer (score 1):

For starters

- der Unsinn — things that contradict common sense
- der Blödsinn — things that come to your mind in a weak moment
- der Schwachsinn — things a dumb person comes up with
- der Irrsinn, der Wahnsinn — things a lunatic person comes up with

and the adjectives are *unsinnig* etc. [But the list of synonyms is huge.](https://synonyme.woxikon.de/synonyme/unsinn.php)

About *sinnlos*, that's the opposite of *sinnvoll* and in general it means that something is not worth doing.